Pass data from a table which is in a particular format as where clause in SQL Query for DB2
The data in a table is of format '123','984' and this should be passed as an input to a column in some other table. I'm not sure whether it is possible however I tried the below query, the data in table 2 for column1 has single quotes with comma separator
select * from table1 where column1 in (select column1 from table2 where column2='XXX')

                               

Table 1 Data                                          Table 2 Data
Column 1   Column 2                        Column1              Column2 
 123         ABC                          '123','984'            XXX
 456         DEF                          '785','812'            XAB
 984         XYZ  

Expected output
Column1     Column 2
  123         ABC
  984         XYZ 


Database normalization is your friend here. This database modeling should be upgraded at least to 1NF.

@TheImpaler I understand however this data is coming from an external system and they would send it this way.

What's the exact format of Table2.Column1 value you have? Is this like in the Table2.Column2='A' or Table2.Column2='B' at the link?

Try this.
Look at the description inside the text of query.
select t1.*
from
(
  values 
    ('123, 984', 'XXX')
  , ('785, 812', 'XAB')
) t2 (Column1, Column2)
-- Tokenizing t2.Column1.
-- Tokens are separated by ','.
-- We get X (by a number of tokens) output rows
-- with the same Column2 value from a single t2 row.
cross join xmltable
(
  'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing 
    t2.Column1 as "s"
  columns 
    tok int path '.'
) t
join
(
  values
    (123, 'ABC')
  , (456, 'DEF')
  , (984, 'XYZ')
) t1 (Column1, Column2) on t1.Column1 = t.tok
where t2.Column2 = 'XXX'





COLUMN1
COLUMN2




123
ABC


984
XYZ



fiddle

Wow... never used XML processing that way in DB2.
